# How To Insert CurrentDate into Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im working on a project similar to Craigslist, and I want to import the date into the colum "CurrentDate" upon submission of the form. I would like to get my code fixed as im sure there are a couple of mistakes.

I haven't tried much since the website is still work in progress.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
  $itemname = $_POST['itemname'];
  $category = $_POST['category'];
  $subcategory = $_POST['subcategory'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  if($name !='' || $email !='') {
    $query = mysql_query("insert into posts(itemname, category, subcategory, price) VALUES (NOW()'$itemname', '$category', '$subcategory', '$price')");
    echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
  }
}
```

I expect to have the current date exported in the field.

SQL Sequence: 
[image: sql]

Comment: share your table structure

Comment: Please don't run this on a production server. You are very vunerable to SQL injection indeed.

Comment: @BenHillier Dont worry! Its running on an unindexed website.

Comment: **TYPO** `NOW()'$itemname',` need a comma .. `NOW(), '$itemname',` and you did not name the column that will contain the NOW() either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$itemname = $_POST['itemname'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$subcategory = $_POST['subcategory'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$cur_date = date('Y-m-d');
if($name !=''||$email !=''){
$query = mysql_query("insert into posts(current_date,itemname, category, subcategory, price) VALUES ($cur_date,'$itemname', '$category', '$subcategory', '$price')");
echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
}
else{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
}
```

this is another way to do, this will store only current date in YYYY-MM-DD format not the time.
if you want to store time as well then use now() instead of $cur_date in sql query or
use $cur_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Answer (score -1):

You have missed a comma, and not named the column you want to insert into:

```
$itemname = $_POST['itemname'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$subcategory = $_POST['subcategory'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
if($name !=''||$email !=''){

    //Add the name of the column here, and put a comma in the values list
    $query = mysql_query("insert into posts(CurrentDate, itemname, category, subcategory, price) VALUES (NOW(),'$itemname', '$category', '$subcategory', '$price')");

    //You are also telling the user the query ran successfully, without actually checking the value of $query to confirm if that is so.
    echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
}
else{
    echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
}
```

Then: Please pay attention to the warnings you are receiving about running this on a production server. Learn about SQL injection and paramaterized queries. This will also not work on any version of PHP after 5.6, which is also end-of-life and no longer maintained for security fixes.

So: Question answered, but a few learning hints for you to continue with.

Comment: Its a typo. We normally make a simple [COMMENT like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57091984/how-to-insert-currentdate-into-table#comment100705942_57091984) and then Vote To Close as a TYPO. The reason being that TYPO's are almost never any use to others, and that is afterall the main purpose of SO

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's true, I wouldn't want others using this code as an example. However, you and I both have taken this opportunity to educate yet another user about SQL injection. It's true that might not add much to this site, since I see several of these go by each day

Comment: Dont think I didn't see that :)